# Interpretation of model diagram for allocation of foreign/primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yEiy.jpg

I am totally confused as to what I should identify as the primary key for the flatpack components table. For the flatpack components, there is a multiplicty relationship with both of the other tables, although intuitively I am leaning toward the component table because that seems more relevant, and the multiplicity is 0 to Many to 1, as opposed to the Many to 1 associated with flatpack components.

I have tried a composite key of both flatpackID and componentNo, but have ran into errors whilst trying to populate the table with sample data.

At present, I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `flatpack_apn` (
    `flatpackid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    `colour` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `flatpacktype` ENUM('Office','Kitchen','Bedroom','General') NOT NULL,
    `unitprice` DECIMAL(5,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`flatpackid`)
)
COLLATE='hp8_english_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2217
;

CREATE TABLE `component_apn` (
    `componentno` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `description` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`componentno`)
)
COLLATE='hp8_english_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=20
;
```

For the flatpackcomponents_apn table (the table in contention) I have tentatively put the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE `flatpackcomponents_apn` (
    `flatpackid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '12',
    `componentno` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '23',
    `quantity` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`componentno`, `flatpackid`),
    INDEX `flatpackid` (`flatpackid`),
    INDEX `componentno` (`componentno`),
    CONSTRAINT `flatpackcomponents_apn_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`flatpackid`) REFERENCES `flatpack_apn` (`flatpackid`),
    CONSTRAINT `flatpackcomponents_apn_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`componentno`) REFERENCES `component_apn` (`componentno`)
)
COLLATE='hp8_english_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Comment: It looks like the expected table required for a many-to-many relationship between your flatpack and component entities. The primary key looks like what I would expect. It ensures that you have at most one row for each pair of flatpackid and componentno values.

Comment: When you ask a question on Stack Overflow and you mention an error, you will predictably be asked, "what was the exact error?"

Comment: FYI you don't need to define an index for a foreign key. That was true in some ancient version of MySQL, but not for 10+ years. The foreign key will use an existing index if one is present, but if not, the FK will create an index. In this case, the index you define for flatpackid is redundant because the FK can use the left column of the primary key.

Comment: Ok, I was not aware of that about the no need to specify index for a foreign key, I was just trying to cover myself. So thank you for that! :) Can you elaborate please on your comment, "The primary key looks like what I would expect": does that mean that I was correct in making a composite key of `componentno`,and `flatpackid`?

Comment: If you define the PK on just one of those columns, for example flatpackid alone, that would mean only one row could exist for a given flatpackid. So you would only be able to associate one component with a given flatpack. Is that what you want? Likewise, if you put the PK on componentno alone, it would mean a given component could be referenced on only one row, so it could be associated with at most one flatpack.